# Xamarin Layout problem, how to make tow button at the bottom of the screen

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I'm learning Xamarin's layout and facing the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Validators"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill"  >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition  ></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Entry x:Name="Username" Grid.Row="0" Placeholder="Username" PlaceholderColor="Blue">
                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                        <local:UsernameValidatorBehavior></local:UsernameValidatorBehavior>
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                </Entry>
                <Entry x:Name="Password" Grid.Row="1" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="Password" PlaceholderColor="Blue">
                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                        <local:PasswordValidatorBehavior></local:PasswordValidatorBehavior>
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                </Entry>
                <Entry x:Name="Email" Grid.Row="2" Placeholder="Email" PlaceholderColor="Blue">
                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                        <local:EmailValidatorBehavior></local:EmailValidatorBehavior>
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                </Entry>
            </Grid>
            <Grid VerticalOptions="End" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button x:Name="Submit" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Submit" Clicked="OnButtonClicked"></Button>
                <Button x:Name="Cancel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Cancel" Clicked="Cancel_Clicked"></Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

My question is that I tried using

> `<Grid VerticalOptions="End" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">`

to make two buttons locating at the bottom of the screen, but it shows in the middle of the screen instead. How to solve this problem?

[image: button location]

**UPDATE1**

I modified the Grid and now the xaml is the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Validators"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill"  >
<Grid VerticalOptions="End">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
<RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
<RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
<RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Entry x:Name="Username" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Placeholder="Username" PlaceholderColor="Blue">
<Entry.Behaviors>
<local:UsernameValidatorBehavior></local:UsernameValidatorBehavior>
</Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
<Entry x:Name="Password" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="Password" PlaceholderColor="Blue">
<Entry.Behaviors>
<local:PasswordValidatorBehavior></local:PasswordValidatorBehavior>
</Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
<Entry x:Name="Email" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Placeholder="Email" PlaceholderColor="Blue">
<Entry.Behaviors>
<local:EmailValidatorBehavior></local:EmailValidatorBehavior>
</Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
<Button x:Name="Submit" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="End" Text="Submit" Clicked="OnButtonClicked"></Button>
<Button x:Name="Cancel" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" 
VerticalOptions="End" Text="Cancel" Clicked="Cancel_Clicked"></Button>
</Grid>   
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Right now there is only one Grid with 4 rows and 2 columns. I added

> `VerticalOptions="End"` inside two buttons.

But buttons are still not at the bottom of the screen and what is more, it is even getting worse.
[image: still problem]

Comment: You have three rows, the row index for buttons should be `Gird.Row=2` not `Grid.Row=1`

Comment: You have a StackLayout containing one Grid that contains 2 other Grids.  That's a really complex layout for a simple page.  Try replacing all of that with one Grid with 4 rows and two columns.  You Entry controls can be the first three rows with colspan=2, then your buttons can be the 2 cols on the last row.

Comment: @Jason I did, but buttons are still not at the bottom of the screen

Comment: do you have their VerticalOptions set to "End"?

Comment: @Jason Yes, please check out the Update1

Comment: Get rid of the StackLayout

Comment: @Jason Thanks, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will work perfeclty for you, add VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" to Grid and provide percentage height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Validators"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill">
            <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="7*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Entry x:Name="Username" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Placeholder="Username" PlaceholderColor="Blue">
<Entry.Behaviors>
<local:UsernameValidatorBehavior></local:UsernameValidatorBehavior>
</Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
<Entry x:Name="Password" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="Password" PlaceholderColor="Blue">
<Entry.Behaviors>
<local:PasswordValidatorBehavior></local:PasswordValidatorBehavior>
</Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
<Entry x:Name="Email" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Placeholder="Email" PlaceholderColor="Blue">
<Entry.Behaviors>
<local:EmailValidatorBehavior></local:EmailValidatorBehavior>
</Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
<Button x:Name="Submit" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Text="Submit" Clicked="OnButtonClicked"></Button>
<Button x:Name="Cancel" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" 
VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Text="Cancel" Clicked="Cancel_Clicked"></Button>
</Grid>   
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```